# Why is the user being created although an error is catched?

Tags: node.js, postman

I am developing an API and in my route to register user i have a try catch block where it catches or not a server error and depending on that the user is created or not.

This is my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { check , validationResult } = require('express-validator/');
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route   POST api/users
//@desc    Register user
//@access  public

router.post('/', [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Plese include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters').isLength({min:6})
], 
async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors:errors.array()}); //400 is for bad requests
    }


    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try{
        //See if user exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'User already exists' }] });
        }

        //Get users gravatar
        const avatar = gravatar.url(email,{
            s:'200',
            r:'pg',
            d:'mm'
        })

        user = new User({
            name,
            email,
            avatar,
            password
        });
    
        //Encrypt password
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        await user.save();
    
        //Return jsonwebtoken -> this for users to be logged in right after registration
        const payload = {
            user:{
                id: user.id
            }
        }
        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            {expiresIn: 360000}, //change to 3600 for production
            (err, token)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });
            } 
        )

    } catch(err) {
        console.error('err.message');
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
    

});

module.exports = router;
```

As i send my request is get as a respond a server error with a status code of 500 but then the user is created anyways. Why is this happening?

Comment: Log what the error is. Get in the habit of debugging and reading errors, don't ignore them. It's clear that some code is failing after `user.save()` finishes.

Comment: Seems like you want `err.message` rather than `'err.message'`

Comment: very likely the error is thrown by the `jwt.sign()` call and not from the user creation part.